# ReactJS: html doesn't see javascript file if type set to text/javascript

Tags: reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Add React in One Minute</title>

  <!-- <script src="app.js" type="text/jsx"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.22.0/aws-sdk.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

  <script type="text/jsx" src="./app.js" >
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code in `app.js` I am running:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I set to `<script src="app.js" type="text/babel">`, it prints nothing.

When I set to `<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript">`, it prints

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

How can I set it so that the code runs correctly?

Comment: You should use `ReactDOM.render` for rendering

Comment: @JozefCipa, nope, didn't work

Comment: @AmazingDayToday use ReactDOM.render and don't use type attr.

Comment: Could you show the whole file where you're including this script ?

Comment: Using it, not using `type attr`, no help @EugeneTsakh

Comment: That's strange. Are you using Webpack or just babel?

Comment: @JozefCipa added

Comment: @EugeneTsakh, nope, static

Comment: Please try type="application/javascript" or type="application/jsx"

Comment: @MehmetAliPeker, nope, yaramadi

Comment: @AmazingDayToday so you are not using anything to transpile JSX?

Comment: You need something that will transpile your JSX code. Why is `babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js` commented ?

Comment: @EugeneTsakh, what should I use?

Comment: Take a look on this https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx

Comment: @EugeneTsakh, this is what I get when I use the browser.js: `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: @AmazingDayToday as far as I understand you don't have anything to transpile the JSX to JS. Try to set up your project with create-react-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Comment: @EugeneTsakh, thanks, it's cool, but I want all to be static, with no `localhost` or some sort of server (

Comment: @AmazingDayToday it's not a server. Basically browsers does not handle JSX and you need a transpiler to convert it to ES5/6 so the browser will be able to process it. So you are writing your code with JSX, then you transpile it and only after that you can use it as a static asset